# php curl POST not returnning anything

Tags: php, curl

I have the following php Curl code, to submit a form and get the tables of result

```
<?php
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
  //echo 1;
  $postData = '';
   //create name value pairs seperated by &
   foreach($params as $k => $v) 
   { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
   }
   rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);    

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    //return $params;
    return $output;
}

$params = array(
        "form_hf_0"=>null,
        "searchMode:edit"=>"Births",
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:regNumber:regNumber"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:regNumber:regYear"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:subjectName:familyName:edit"=>"smith",
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:subjectName:givenName:edit"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:subjectName:otherNames:edit"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:fatherGivenName:edit"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:fatherOtherNames:edit"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:motherGivenName:edit"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:motherOtherNames:edit"=>null,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:dateOfEvent:range:edit"=>true,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:dateOfEvent:switchGroup:range:dateFrom:day"=>01,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:dateOfEvent:switchGroup:range:dateFrom:month"=>01,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:dateOfEvent:switchGroup:range:dateFrom:year"=>1788,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:dateOfEvent:switchGroup:range:dateTo:day"=>31,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:dateOfEvent:switchGroup:range:dateTo:month"=>12,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:dateOfEvent:switchGroup:range:dateTo:year"=>1913,
        "searchSwitch:birthContainer:district:edit"=>null,
        "search-button"=>"Search"
);

 $param1 = array("username"=>"sa","password"=>"1");
echo httpPost("https://lifelink.bdm.nsw.gov.au/lifelink/familyhistory/search?0-2.IFormSubmitListener-mainContent-form",$params);

?>
```

The form link is here:https://lifelink.bdm.nsw.gov.au/lifelink/familyhistory/search?0
I have nothing printed.
Can anyone pointed  where is wrong?
The result is here http://ec2-54-213-181-25.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/htdocs/lib/CURL/curl.php
Nothing in the table as normal search with family name "smith", range date 1788 to 1914.

Comment: Yikes, Apache Wicket forms are tricky enough when you're writing the Java code ;). Seriously though, have you enabled `display_errors` in your dev environment and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`?

Comment: the form is not mine, I just want to extract data from that search by cURL

Comment: You could enable the CURLOPT_VERBOSE option to debug what could be going wrong: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Comment: I put that line in and still get no result? any tricky thing with that form?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in `POST` data you send. How `$params` array is populated before passing to `httpPost`?

Comment: Can you try the form with family name SMITH , range 1788 to 1914 ? I am really stuck with that